# How to restore an INVISIBLE view to be VISIBLE again when its space on the layout is touched?

Tags: android, view, touch, ontouchlistener

Simply, I want when touching a `textView` to set it`invisible` and when touch the same area of the screen on which the `view` was `visible`, to set it `visible` again. Please refer to the code below, it might clarify more the task i am intending to achieve.

Code:

```
targetTv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "button is touched @view ("+v.getX()+","+v.getY()+")");
            Log.i(TAG, "button is touched @event ("+event.getX()+","+event.getY()+")");

            if (targetTv.getVisibility() == targetTv.VISIBLE) {
                targetTv.setVisibility(targetTv.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                targetTv.setVisibility(targetTv.VISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: to achieve that you will have one mote transparent view on the targetTv   and visible the targetTv on another view touch.

Comment: @RaviKant how to have a transparent view on the `targettv`? could you please provide an example?

Comment: Use RelativeLayout as parent of targetTv and another view and set view at the same position of targetTv in layout.xml

Comment: @RaviKant i did as you advised, and I tried to set the second `textview` as transparent using `setTextColor(Color.argb(0,255, 0, 0));` but it did not work?

Answer (score 0):

When the view is invisible, no events dispatched to it.

Because of that, you should wrap your view with a layout that is always visible, so it can detect events even when the contained View is invisible.

Then you have to add an onClickListener to the container, that toogles the visibility of the wrapped item.

Comment: I wrapped my `textview` inside a `relativelayout`. but i do not know why i should use `onclicklistener`? i need to listen to touches only.?

Comment: You can use onTouchListener also.

Comment: ok, i am using `ontouchlistener`. and i tried to set the second `textview` that should overcast/hide my original `textview` t be transparent using `setTextColor(Color.argb(0,255, 0, 0))` but it does not work